# index.php:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help. I have created a small script to send push notifications. Except that when I send the notification from the administration panel, the user has problems receiving as he has this error:

```html
index.php: 27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success (index.php: 27)
    at c (jquery-3.4.1.min.js: 2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js: 2)
    at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js: 2)
    at XMLHttpRequest. <anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js: 2)
```

below part of my code

```js
setInterval(function() {
  check_notification();
}, 10000);

function check_notification() {
  var Uid = ReadCookie("Uid");
  if (Uid !== undefined) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch_notifications.php?user_id=" + Uid,
      success: function(result) {
        var response = JSON.parse(result);
        if (response.status == 1) {
          response = response.notifications;
          for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var url = response[i]['url'];
            var noti = new Notification(response[i]['title'], {
              icon: 'logo.png',
              body: response[i]['body'],
            });
            noti.onclick = function() {
              window.open(url);
              noti.close();
            };

          };

        } else {
          console.log(response.error);

        }

      }

    });
  }
}
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: `response.notifications` is undefined, so you need to check the response generated from the PHP code calles in your AJAX request. Given the code in the question, that's all the help we can really offer.

Comment: Just check if there is a `notifications` property before moving ahead: `if (response.status == 1 && response.notifications)`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Looking at the new PHP code you posted, the problem is that you are trying to access response.notifications, whereas the property is named "notification", without the 's'.

Are you sure your understanding of the JSON response's structure is correct? The error is occuring because the response (JSON object) does not contain the property "notifications". I'd suggest opening up fetch_notifications.php in your browser and double checking the structure of the response.